# Find hostname in a text file within directory, and rename the directory to the hostname

Tags: text-processing, macos

The hostname is included in the text file `/sys/info` with the format

```
Host Name: xxxxxxx
```

I want to fetch the hostname (in this case `xxxxxxx`) from `/sys/info` and rename the parent directory to be the same as that hostname.

Comment: The `/sys/info` file, does it have any particular structure (is it a YAML or JSON file)? Does that file contain anything other than what you show in the question? What is the parent directory? Is it `/sys` or the directory given by `dirname "$PWD"`? What should happen if there is a name collision? Can you bypass the text file and instead use `hostname` or `hostname -s` (assuming it's the local host)? If not, consider updating the question to say "a hostname" rather than "the hostname".

Comment: Is there anything you tried we can help you with?

Comment: You want to rename `/sys` to `/xxxxxxx`? That doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to find directories containing a `sys/info` file inside them and rename them to the `Host name` inside that file, that could be something like:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -depth -path './*/sys/info' -type f -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    if host=$(grep -Poxm1 "Host Name:\s*\K\S+" < "$file"); then
       echo mv -iT -- "${file%/sys/info}" "${file%/*/sys/info}/$host"
    fi
  done' sh {} +
```

(assuming GNU `grep` and GNU `mv`; untested).

Remove the `echo` to do it.